# ColdFusion: Are there any use cases where an Application.cfm is preferable to an Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc, application.cfm

I'm in the process of upgrading a large legacy ColdFusion application that heavily utilizes `Application.cfm` template files instead of the newer `Application.cfc` files.

It seems that `Application.cfc` offer a cleaner more efficient solution to everything that a Application.cfm file can do.

- An `Application.cfm` runs every line sequentially for every request, so
  it would recreate application variables on every subsequent new page query. 
  (Can cause performance hit if many
  application variables loaded)  `The Application.cfc` allows for certain truely global variables to avoid getting recreated with the `onApplicationStart()` and `onRequestStart()` method

Has anyone come across any use cases/examples(apart from the obvious time it takes to port) where `Application.cfm` pages are preferable to `Application.cfc`

Comment: It's a question of whether or not the reward justifies the work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO, this is not "too broad" a topic. This isn't an opinion, I'd classify it as a Best Practice.

There are vast number of reasons to use the `cfc` over the `cfm`. I've been in this exact situation.

Here's a [list of the common functions](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/) available in `Application.cfc` (I'm sure you're aware):

- onApplicationStart()
- onSessionStart()
- onRequestStart()
- onRequest()
- onRequestEnd()
- onSessionEnd()
- onApplicationEnd()
- onError()

Without getting into the details of each, having the ability to sort your code into contextual buckets like these will allow you to better manage your various variable scopes. Without these contextual triggers, you're just replying on the procedural aspects of the `Application.cfm`.

While both are run on every page request, only certain functions in the `cfc` are run. The `cfm`, you have code running all the time, checking conditions for when it should or should not be run.

Sticking with the `cfm` is certainly less risky, but if you're upgrading it, you should expect that you'll break things along the way. Adopting best practices should be part of this process.

Comment: I agree with everything on this list, but I feel like adding one more. Because it is a cfc, it can use extends. There are rich frameworks like FW/1 and Taffy which tap into that. Also I think if you want to use ORM, you have to use application.cfc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! So I definitely see the benefit of the .CFC over the .CFM, but are there any good reasons someone would ever use a CFM over the CFC in modern application that applies best practices?

Comment: IF I had to take care of 15 year old computer that was running CF 5, AND it was making the company millions per day AND I was told to never touch AND I was allowed to complain about the setup every day AND my kid had cancer AND my wife was having her arms and legs amputated, and the cat wanted tuna, THEN I would leave it alone. The only reason to use `application.cfm` is you just don't want to bother with it.